# when i re-size my browser all element change their place

Tags: javascript, html, css

when i re-size my browser  all element change their place can any one help me ???  but some of element like logo & navigation when i re-size the browser Not affected 
i tried to make the position fixed absolute or  static but nothing change

```
<head>
<title>www.adamkides.com/main</title>
<link rel="icon" href="logo.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?     family=Archivo+Narrow:700italic,700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
a{color:black;}
body {
font-family: 'Lucida Grande', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
background: white;
background-size:101%;
height:100%;

background-image: url('dr5.jpg'); 

background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin:-70 0 0 0;
}
 #face:hover {
background: #333;

border-left: 5px solid #000;
}
#face{    MARGIN-LEFT: -850PX;
MARGIN-TOP: 1PX;}
#container
{            
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
background: #fff;
 }
#header
{
background-image: url(hand.jpg);
background-size: 310px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color:white;
width: 320px;
height: 100px;
float:right;
margin: 70px 500px -11px 0%;
 }

 #header h1 { margin: 0; }
.navigation {
margin: 5px 20px 30px 20%;
background: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
width: 760px;
float: left;
padding-left: 100px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 }

.navigation li {
width: 120px; border-left: 5px solid #666;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 10px 50px 10px 15px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
 }

.navigation li h2 {
font-family: georgia;
font-weight: bold;
font-style:arial;
font-size: 20px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
line-height: 16px;
   }

.navigation li p{
font-size: 11px;
color: #999;

-webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
-o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
   }

.navigation li:hover {
background: greenyellow;
border-left: 5px solid #000;
 }

.navigation li:hover h2 {
font-weight: bold;
color: yellow;
 }

.navigation li:hover p {
color: orange;
padding-left: 5px;
 }
 #content-container
 {           float: left;
 width: 55%;
    margin-top: -25px;

margin-left: 320px;
height: 60%;
background: #FFF url(layout-two-liquid-background.gif) repeat-y 68% 0;
 }
.ti{
   border-color: greenyellow;
border-style: dotted;
margin-top: -70px;
border-width: thin;
width: 235px;
height: 250px;
margin-left: 295px;
font-size: 24px;
color: orange;
font-weight: 700;}
#content {
  clear: right;
float: left;
width: 60%;
padding: 5px 0;
margin: -14px -41px -294px 7%;
display: inline;
 }

#content h2 { margin: 0; }

#aside
{
float: right;
width: 26%;
padding: 20px 0;
margin: 15 320 0 0;
display: inline;
}

 #aside h3 { margin: 0; }

 #footer{margin: 30px 20px -2px 0px;
overflow: hidden;

 border-color: greenyellow;
border-style: dotted;
border-width: thin;
width: 760px;
height:100px;
background-color:white;
float: left;
padding-left: 100px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<img src="logo1.jpg" width="50px" height="50px" style="margin-top: 75px;margin-left: 522px;/* border:solid; *//* border-color:#ef5d9b; */height: 100px;float: left;width: 100px;">      <div id="header" style="background-image: url(hand.jpg);">
</div>
<ul class="navigation">
<a href="mainpage.html"><li>
    <h2>الصفحة الرئسية</h2>
    <p>main page</p>
</li></a>
<a href="f.html"><li>
    <h2>فلسفتنا</h2>
    <p>our</p>
</li></a>
<a href="how.html"><li>
    <h2>من نحن</h2>
    <p>Who we are</p>
</li></a>
<a href="gallary.html"><li>
    <h2>الاستديو</h2>
    <p>gallary</p>
</li></a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ADAM.KIDS.JORDAN/?fref=ts"><image id="face" src="face.jpg" width="80px" height="80px"/></a>

</ul>
<div id="content-container">
    <div id="content">
        <h2 style="float:right;font-size:50px;color:green;"><img src="well.jpg" width="70px" height="70px"style="margin-top:10px;">     كلمة ترحيبية    </h2>
        <p align="right"style="float:right;font-size:25px ;margin-left:-10px;color:black;">
        مرحباً بكم في صفحتنا التي عملنا بجهد متواضع لنجعل منها موقعاً متميزاً يخدم الجميع ، ليس فقط أهالي أطفال الروضة بل و أيضاً الزبائن الكرام ، و نتمنى أن تكون مرجعاً مفيداً لكم، و أن تكون حلقة وصل بيننا و بينكم ، . . . فلا تترددوا بتزويدنا بكل مقترحاتكم و آرائكم التي تساعدنا على التطور نحو الأفضل واعلموا أن رأيكم مهم لدينا وسيساعدنا على لتطور .
نأمل أن تجدوا المعلومات التي تبحثون عن
ها على موقعنا الالكتروني
 ، ولمزيد من المعلومات أو الاستفسارات الرجاء طلب ذلك، 
 وسوف يسعد نا توفيرها لكم نتطلع إلى الترحيب بكم في 
 روضتنا ونأمل أن يعودو أطفالكم بذكريات جميلة و تجربة
 فريدة.
            </p>

    </div>
    <div id="aside">
        <h3>
  <div class="ti" >
 <p id="time"style="margin-left:20%;margin-top:70px;"></p>

  <script>
  var x=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);

   function myTimer() {
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}</script>
<p id="date"style="margin-left:15%"></p>
<p style="margin-left:30%"><a href="game.html" style="color:green;">اتسلى    معنى</a></p>
 <script>
  var d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d.toDateString();
   </script><br><br>
   </script>
 </div>
</div>
  <div id="footer"><h2 style="margin-top:7px;float:right;margin-right:30px;color:green;font-size:30px;">:اتصل بنا</h2></div>
<h4 style="font-size:18px;float:right;margin-top:-60px;margin-right:50px;">065925575 - 0796877760<br> 065925575 فاكس </h4>
<h2 style="margin-top:-94px;float:left;margin-left:30px;color:green;font-size:30px;">:البريد الالكتروني</h2>
<h4><a style="margin-left:30px;margin-top:-40px;clear:left;color:black;float:left;font-size:18px;" href="mailto:info@adam-kids.com">info@adam-kids.com</a></h4 >
  <h2 style="float:right;margin-top:-100px;margin-right:150px;color:green;font-size:30px;">:العنوان</h2>
   <h4 style="margin-bottom: auto;margin-top:-67px;margin-right:80px;font-size:18px;width:190px;float:right;">
 بناية رقم 9 - شارع علي سيدو الكردي
  - خلف كنيسة اللاتين - عبدون الشمالي
 - عمان - الأردن


</h4>

</div>

</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? That everything moves, or that nothing moves when resizing? Also, you should use external css files http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: You code sample is a disaster, mixed inline/external styles, using properties like the margin for the complete wrong things, and so on. I urge you to go through a tutorial before continue with the development. ... Check this google result: https://www.google.com/search?q=good%20web%20development%20tutorials&rct=j

Comment: Your settings are set like "static" ones what means it is fixed to one size of screen only. You need to learn more about positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because you're mixing fixed units and relative units in your CSS.

Fixed units like pixels keeps the especified sizes even when you resize your browser, while relative units like percentages reacts and adapts to resizing.

Consider that fixed units will create a lot of horizontal scroll depending on the device your site it's being viewed from, but relative units will reorganize your page for a better presentation, that's what we call "Responsive".

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your CSS responsive. By responsive, I mean that your CSS should be able to react to the different browser widths and heights.

This is a massive topic but a good place to start might be here:

> http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_responsive_intro.asp

You should also look into CSS frameworks such as Bootstrap or Foundation:

> http://getbootstrap.com/
>
> http://foundation.zurb.com/

Both of which have plenty of online tutorials you can learn from. The w3schools link I have provided gives you a basic introduction to Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Use the browser development tool to see the properties of elements and inspect why they are behaving that way. For your example, the ul with the 'navigation' class has margin-left set to 20%, which makes it change position when the total width of the page changes.

I have to agree with the others, though, and ask you to read more about the subject so you can understand the samples you are working with.